# Pass variable form to class and retrieve it from another form

Tags: c#

C# situation....i've set a value to a variable from another class using form1 using this...

**CLASS**

```
 public int _a;
        public int a
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return _a;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        _a = value;
                    }
}
```

**Form 1**

```
  private void btnchangevalue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
class x = new class();
x.a = 1;
}
```

**Form 2**

```
private void btngetvalue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    class x = new class();
   messagebox.show(x.a);
    }
```

the problem is the class variable that ive set always turns to **null** when i've tried to retrieve it..

Comment: Can you provide proper code? `class` is a reserved keyword in C# and as such this wouldn't work. Also, you've declared `public int _a` but you're treating it as if it's private..

Comment: I presume this is a Windows Forms program? You should tell us so we don't have to presume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a **static variable**

static variable is a variable that has been allocated statically, whose lifetime extends across the entire run of the program.

`public static int a`

What is happening is that new variables
Are created each time
You create the form object

Comment: do i need to use setter and getter?

Answer (score 0):

Well i think its because you are instantiating a new instance of class every time....create a new instance of class once and then just use the same whenever you click the button.

```
class x = new class();
private void btnchangevalue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x.a = 1;
}

private void btngetvalue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    messagebox.show(x.a);
}
```